# vb.net Webbroswer strange occurence

Tags: vb.net, webbrowser-control

I have a vb.net webbrowser control that goes to a website and logs in automatically. It works just fine even when someone enters a wrong password in the form. but once the right password is entered after a wrong password, the login form pops up a second time and they have to enter the user/password again and it will work the second time around. I have included the full code for the webbrowser form. Another weird thing that happens when this same issue above happens is it will pop up a default browser to the url listed but with this at the end http://url%20-%20#b8716a8 
Any ideas?

```
Imports System.IO
Imports Microsoft.Win32
Public Class frm_webbrowser    
Private cntAttempts1 = 0
Private Const BrowserKeyPath As String = "\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\MAIN\FeatureControl\FEATURE_BROWSER_EMULATION"

Private Sub frm_webbrowser_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

        CreateBrowserKey()
        WebBrowser1.ScriptErrorsSuppressed = True
        WebBrowser1.Navigate(“url", "_top", Nothing, "User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/43.0.2357.130 Safari/537.36")

    End If
End Sub

Private Sub frm_webbrowser_FormClosing(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As FormClosingEventArgs) Handles Me.FormClosing
    RemoveBrowerKey()
End Sub

Private Sub CreateBrowserKey(Optional ByVal IgnoreIDocDirective As Boolean = False)
    Dim basekey As String = Microsoft.Win32.Registry.CurrentUser.ToString
    Dim value As Int32
    Dim thisAppsName As String = My.Application.Info.AssemblyName & ".exe"

    Select Case (New WebBrowser).Version.Major
        Case 8
            If IgnoreIDocDirective Then
                value = 8888
            Else
                value = 8000
            End If
        Case 9
            If IgnoreIDocDirective Then
                value = 9999
            Else
                value = 9000
            End If
        Case 10
            If IgnoreIDocDirective Then
                value = 10001
            Else
                value = 10000
            End If

        Case 11
            If IgnoreIDocDirective Then
                value = 11001
            Else
                value = 11000
            End If
        Case Else
            Exit Sub
    End Select
    Microsoft.Win32.Registry.SetValue(Microsoft.Win32.Registry.CurrentUser.ToString & BrowserKeyPath,
                                      Process.GetCurrentProcess.ProcessName & ".exe",
                                      value,
                                      Microsoft.Win32.RegistryValueKind.DWord)
End Sub

Private Sub RemoveBrowerKey()
    Dim key As Microsoft.Win32.RegistryKey
    key = Microsoft.Win32.Registry.CurrentUser.OpenSubKey(BrowserKeyPath.Substring(1), True)
    key.DeleteValue(Process.GetCurrentProcess.ProcessName & ".exe", False)
End Sub

Private Sub WebBrowser1_DocumentCompleted(sender As Object, e As WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs) Handles WebBrowser1.DocumentCompleted

    WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("username").SetAttribute("value", user.Text)
    WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("password").SetAttribute("value", pass.Text)
    WebBrowser1.Document.All("submit").InvokeMember("click")

    cntAttempts1 += 1

    If cntAttempts1 = 3 Then
        cntAttempts1 = 0
        WebBrowser1.Stop()
        MsgBox("Invalid username/password please re-enter.")
        Dim box = New frm_weblogin()
        box.Show()
        Me.Close()
    End If

End Sub
Private Sub WebBrowser1_NewWindow(sender As Object, e As System.ComponentModel.CancelEventArgs) Handles WebBrowser1.NewWindow
    e.Cancel = True
    WebBrowser1.Navigate(WebBrowser1.StatusText)
End Sub
```

Comment: I'm guessing that because you're always incrementing `cntAttempts1` on the DocumentCompleted event, if the login fails twice, then even if it succeeds the third time, `cntAttempts1 = 3` and so it's running your Invalid username code anyway and displaying the login form again. Instead of trying to count failed login attempts, you should probably change your DocumentCompleted code to read the document body to determine if the login succeeded.

Comment: i tried that originally but on the page there is absolutely no change at invalid login, it basically just refreshes the current page.

Comment: Navigate the webbrowser to the login page so it's waiting for credentials. Show your login form. In your `Login` button click event on your form, execute the `SetAttribute` methods passing the credentials and invoke the `Click` event...remove those from the DocumentCompleted event. You shouldn't need the `cntAttempts1` either. Change the DocumentCompleted event to look for success/failure. You say when it fails it just refreshes and the page is the same, so success means it's different, correct? Find out what's different when it successfully logs in and that will tell you success or failure.

Comment: This does not work because it does not wait for the webpage to finish loading before attempting to login.

Comment: You say _it does not wait..._ , what does not wait? You have a form that prompts for login credentials, correct? If the form is waiting for the user to type something, the webpage should have already loaded the login page and it should be waiting for login credentials also.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If anyone else is interested I was able to fix this by putting the following code in the DocumentCompleted.

```
If e.Url.AbsolutePath <> TryCast(sender, WebBrowser).Url.AbsolutePath Then
    Return
End If
```

The weird pop up I was getting in my default browser was caused by the MsgBox so I just removed it and created a form that said the username/password was invalid and had the login fields.